# Como dar efeito hover de opacidade em img's?

Tags: css

Queria saber como coloca efeito hover das img's desse site http://digitaltheme.co/html/admag/demo/index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente colocar um fundo escuro e dar opacidade na imagem ao passar o mouse que dará esse efeito. Um exemplo seria assim:

```css
.darken {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    padding: 0;
}


.darken:hover img {
    opacity: 0.7;      
}
.darken img {
    display: block;
    
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
            transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" class="darken">
    <img src="http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg" width="200">
</a>
```

Onde estou colocando o fundo escuro com este código:

```
.darken {
        display: inline-block;
        background: black;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Se quiser entender melhor o funcionamento, altere essa linha `background: black;` para outra cor, por exemplo: `background: blue;` que ficará azul ao invés de preto.

E ao passar o mouse, setando a opacidade dele, nesta parte:

```
.darken:hover img {
        opacity: 0.7;      
    }
```

A última parte é somente para transição.

Fonte: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1747655/4843158)

Comment: valeu cara me ajudou muito !!